# Derive the Lemma of Christoffel symbol

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, general-relativity, special-relativity

> Derive the Lemma of Christoffel symbol, $$\frac{\partial^2x^\rho}{\partial\bar x^\mu\partial\bar x^\nu}=\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\gamma\frac{\partial x^\rho}{\partial\bar x^\gamma}-\frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial\bar x^\mu}\frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial\bar x^\nu}\Gamma_{\alpha\beta}^\rho$$

We know that, $$\bar g_{ij}=\frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial \bar x^i}\frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial\bar x^j}g_{\alpha\beta}\tag 1$$
Now, the process my book followed, differentiate $(1)$ with respect to different co-ordinate $\bar x^i$, interchange several variable and use the definition of Christoffel symbol of first kind and multiplying conjugate metric $\bar g^{rk}$. The complete computation was so tedious and it took 5 pages. Now, I can't just memorize that and copy in my exam sheet. Is there any other approach where things were flowing a sequence or I can easily memorize or understand those steps intuitively.

Any solution or external redirect will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: My title might be wrong, as the book mention the heading as **Lemma of chistoffel**. I didn't find something related with this title by googling.

Comment: You can restate this lemma as a rule proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3418797) for transforming Christoffel symbols.

Comment: I have asked some question on that thread. It will be a great help if you clear them @J.G. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As someone who has taught differential geometry — both undergraduate and graduate — numerous times, I would hope that no one teaching a decent course would ever put such a thing on an exam. There are far more interesting questions to ask.

Comment: Are you really expected to memorize the calculation for your exam? One trick that might work is to note that the formula for $A_{\alpha\beta\gamma} = g_{\alpha\delta}\Gamma^\delta_{\beta\gamma}$ in terms of derivatives of $g_{\alpha\beta}$ is much simpler than the one for $\Gamma^\gamma_{\mu\nu}$. So do the whole calculation using $A$ instead of $\Gamma$ and then substitute in the formula for $A$ in terms of $g$ and $\Gamma$ only at the end.